# Bash loop new user

Tags: linux, bash, programming

I have to create 20 users on 10 servers. I want to create a script that will create 20 users for me on the server (that's easy with `useradd`) and encrypt the password. I have my variable

`$crypt=perl -e 'print crypt...'`

Now I want to create a loop that will create the new users and the password will be set by `$crypt`.

How I can do this ?

Comment: Have you examined the `-p` flag of `useradd`?

Comment: Yes, I did useradd [name of user] -p [password] but this method doesn't work because password have to be crypt

Comment: Does your question not say that you have that in a string via perl?

Answer (score 5):

setup crypt

```
crypt=$(perl -e'print crypt("somekey", "salt_character")')
```

call username list in a for loop and pass $crypt for password.

```
for i in `cat usernamelist`
 do
    useradd $i -p $crypt
done
```

from man page,

```
-p, --password PASSWORD
          The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the account.
```

Comment: But each user have a different password :( can I put $pass=cat password.txt and replace salt_character with $pass ??

Comment: for pass in ``cat password.txt``                                                         
     do 
       crypt=$(perl -e'print crypt("$pass", "xx")')
       for usr in `cat userlist.txt`
       do
         useradd $user -p $crypt
       done
    done

Comment: Many distros have the [mkpasswd](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/makepasswd) available.  Which may make generating the hashes easier.  You can also generate sha256/sha512 hashes, which are better security.